# UIActivityViewController contacts sharing?

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to think about a way to share contact using `UIActivityViewController` (or using SMS) from one device to another.

So far I've been looking and I've no idea how can I share contacts between devices using my app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After searching for months, I have finally discovered the way to achieve this.

You can use this code to share a single CNContact in a UIActivityViewController:

```
let contact: CNContact = /* your contact here */

let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let cacheDirectory = try! fileManager.URLForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.CachesDirectory, inDomain: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)

let fileLocation = cacheDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(CNContactFormatter().stringFromContact(contact)!).vcf")

let contactData = try! CNContactVCardSerialization.dataWithContacts([contact])
contactData.writeToFile(fileLocation.path!, atomically: true)

let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileLocation], applicationActivities: nil)
presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This code converts the contact into its NSData representation, saves it to the app's cache folder, and shares the file as an activity item.

If you want to share multiple contacts, you can pass multiple files in this way.

## Edit: Swift 3.0 version

```
let contact: CNContact = /* your contact here */

let fileManager = FileManager.default
let cacheDirectory = try! fileManager.url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

let fileLocation = cacheDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(CNContactFormatter().string(from: contact)!).vcf")

let contactData = try! CNContactVCardSerialization.data(with: [contact])
do {
    try contactData.write(to: fileLocation.asURL(), options: .atomicWrite)
} catch {
    ...
}

let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileLocation], applicationActivities: nil)
present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3.0:

```
    let cacheDirectory = try! FileManager.default.url(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.cachesDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

    let fileLocation = cacheDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(CNContactFormatter().string(from: contact)!).vcf")

    let contactData = try! CNContactVCardSerialization.data(with: [contact])
    do {
        _ = try contactData.write(to: fileLocation, options: .atomic)
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also easily achievable using the old ABAddressBook framework in a similar way (make a vCard representation, save it to file, share the URL):

```
func AB_RecordVcardFileURL(record: ABRecord) -> NSURL? {
    let docsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

    guard let
        pathStr = docsPath.first as NSString?
        else {return nil}

    let name = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(record).takeRetainedValue() ?? "vcard"
    let filePath = pathStr.stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(name!).vcf")

    let fileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

    let card = ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople([record]).takeRetainedValue() as NSData
    card.writeToURL(fileUrl, atomically: true)

    return fileUrl
}
```

Than you just pass the URL to the activity controller:

```
guard let
        fileUrl = AB_RecordVcardFileURL(record)
else {return}

let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileUrl], applicationActivities: nil)
presentViewController(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Version: Swift 4.2 To avoid crash when contact is without name .

```
let cnContact : CNContact = CNContact()
 let fileManager = FileManager.default
        do {
            let cacheDirectory = try? fileManager.url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            let fileLocation = cacheDirectory?.appendingPathComponent("\(CNContactFormatter().string(from: cnContact) ?? "Contact")).vcf")
            let contactData = try? CNContactVCardSerialization.data(with: [cnContact])
            try? contactData?.write(to: (fileLocation?.asURL())!, options: .atomicWrite)
            attachedFiles.append(fileLocation!)
        } catch let error {
            logger.info("share contact failed due to :\(error)")
        }
```

If your contact is not having name filed and when you try to do CNContactFormatter().string(from: cnContact) then it will crash because it will return nil . So to avoid crash give some default name don't do it forcefully .