# How to send contact (.vcf) file via UIActivityViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

I make one app. App generate “ .vcf ” and you want to send that vcf to everyone. My option is send it through email , whatsapp ,and other share apps, and i use UIActivityViewController, but it can’t send whatsapp. I can send image ,video , audio but i can’t send contact. Please help me to solve this problem. I [refere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646019/attach-object-using-ios6-uiactivityviewcontroller) this link and do that thing same as mention but same problem occurred.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code.

Here you check i send every thing image ,audio, video but not able to send contact. So help me.

```
-(void)shareContact
{ 
    //NSString *str = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HAK" ofType:@".mp3"];
    //NSString *str = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"b" ofType:@"png"];
    //NSString *str = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@".mp4"];
      NSString *str = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"vCard" ofType:@".vcf"];
    //NSString *str = [self vCardRepresentation];
      NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:str];
      NSArray *objectsToShare = @[fileUrl];

      UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
      [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIActivityViewController contacts sharing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867580/uiactivityviewcontroller-contacts-sharing)